# Is there any rule for shortening of names of people?

Tags: grammar, proper-nouns

In Louisa May Alcott's novel *Little Women*, four sisters are named Jo, Meg, Amy and Beth respectively, but later I realized their full names are Josephine, Margaret, Amy and Elizabeth respectively. The shortened names and the full ones are so different.

And the same Elizabeth in Jane Austen's novel *Pride and Prejudice* is shortened as Eliza.

William is known to be shortened as Bill. Bill Gates then is William Gates? William Shakespeare is Bill Shakespeare?

My head swims, please anyone, tell me the rule behind this nomenclature.

Comment: There is no rule. Do you really think there could be a "rule" governing the names people use? Who would enforce it? English is exactly like every other language. I'm afraid you'll have to memorize them, and you'll find many that don't make any sense at all!

Comment: By the way: in English, the first name is called the _given name_, and when we shorten it in this way, the English word for the result is _"nickname"_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about learning English.

Comment: @user3169 I think it's on topic, myself, insofar as we can come up with some pattern that at least accounts for certain types of names. The only answer so far talks of there being none, but one can at least depend on English phonotactics to rule out certain substrings. ;) I may come back to formulate an answer later if I can. There's a good Homestar Runner cartoon on this that I remember...

Comment: My point is that proper names are not language specific, and don't change between languages. Shortened given names (or modified surnames) follow the imagination of those creating them.

Comment: A Margaret could be nicknamed Peg or Peggy in addition to Meg, Maggie, Mags. Language is not anarchy. It's mob rule.

Comment: @user3169 I don't know what you mean by proper names not changing between languages. Jehonathan, Jonathan, Johannes, John, Jean, Ivan, Ian, and Jan are all versions of one name after bearing the very distinctive mark of whichever language they pass through.

Comment: Related at EL&U: *[Changes in English names of people](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8767)* and *[Term for nicknames with different first letter](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84744)*.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, and also Daisy.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daisy_(given_name), plus a whole lot more derived from other languages, for example Gretchen...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret

Answer (score 12):

To summarize, there are no hard and fast rules, but there certainly are patterns that can guide us now and then. Each language naturally has its own patterns, so to my mind this is a legitimate question about English.

---

#### From short name to long name

There certainly is no way to guess what someone's full name is just from their short name, simply because information is missing. *Meg* contains few of the  letters of *Margaret*. So you have to memorize it. And even English speakers don't know all of these connections. Just recently I was wondering if *Curdie* was short for another name after reading [The Princess and the Goblin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Princess_and_the_Goblin). (It isn't.)

And even when you do know the full list, you can guess wrong! If I meet someone named Jo, I don't know whether her full name is Josephine, Joanne, or Joanna. The original information from the full name just isn't recoverable. No doubt this is the same in any language.

---

#### From long name to short name

However, the other direction, trying to determine the short name based on the long name, is a little more promising. I will stress what the others have stressed so far: there are no hard and fast rules. But there are tendencies.

In the bizarre Homestar Runner cartoon "[do over](http://hrwiki.org/wiki/do_over)", there's a tongue-in-cheek sequence where Strong Bad takes the names Ashley and Anthony and tries to create nicknames for them:

> Well, *Ash* and *Ant*, or *Ley* and *Thony*, or *Shle* and *Ntho*, or whatever you like to be called...

English speakers instantly recognize the last four as wrong. But they're wrong for interesting reasons.

- *Ntho* for *Anthony* has a syllable-initial cluster /nθ/, which is impossible in English [phonotactics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonotactics). You can instantly rule out any short form of that kind!
- *Shle* for *Ashley* can also be ruled out. We do allow /ʃl/ at the start of some borrowed names (e.g. Shlomo). But *Shle* has been broken at the wrong place in the word. It begins at a syllable coda instead of an onset. That is either disallowed or extremely rare.
- *Ley* for *Ashley* is very unlikely. Why? Because it's formed from an unstressed syllable in *Ashley* (and one that sounds like just a diminutive suffix<sup>1</sup> — more on that later). Short names are usually based on the primary stressed syllable: *Rob* for ***Rob***ert, *Bert* for ***Ber***trand, *Randy* for ***Ran***dall. (There are exceptions, such as *E**liz**abeth* → *Beth* from the secondary stressed syllable or even → *El* from an unstressed syllable.)
- For this reason, *Ash* is the correct and probably the only possible short form for *Ashley*.
- *Thony* for *Anthony* is unlikely for a more complex reason. The correct form is *Tony*, which is a name originally more popular among Italians and hence based on the Italian version *An**to**nio*: where the stress is on *-to-* (ruling out *Ant*) and it has no *h* (ruling out *Thony*).
- For this reason, *Ant* (sometimes *Anth*) corresponds to the Anglicized pronunciation ***An***thony.<sup>2</sup>

We can also add the use of a [diminutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive) suffix. A common one is *-y* / *-ie*. This is what allows for *Ellie* (← *Elizabeth*), *Jordie* (← *Jordan*), *Billy* (← *William*), *Sandy* (← *Sandra*), *Debbie* (← *Deborah*), *Danny* (← *Daniel*), and many more. This is also why any English speaker might assume that *Curdie* is a short form, perhaps for *Curtis*: there is some regularity in the system!

It's true that some of these diminutives may be appended to an existing short form (e.g. it could be *Daniel* → *Dan* → *Danny*), but some of them replace parts of the longer name. To my knowledge, we have no short form *Jord* or *Sand*.

So those are some general guidelines for how to clip names to make shorter ones. We might be able to understand *Josephine*, for example. The primary stressed syllable *Jo* is inherently the most likely. I could also buy *Feeny*, taken from the secondary stressed syllable plus a diminutive. But the unstressed syllable *Seph* would be impossible.

But finally we must return to the observation that many names are not guessable. Among the most infamous are *Margaret* → *Peg*, *William* → *Bill*, and *Richard* → *Dick*. These names were crystallized long ago according to the phonology of an older English or even of a different language. (A linguist can see a reason for /w/ → /b/ or /m/ → /p/, but most of us are better off just to memorize these names.) I suspect that the older the name, the more unpredictable it is and the more variants it has.

And of course even our guidelines and patterns can be broken wilfully. Names are very personal and come with stories attached to them. P.E.Dant gives the example of *Card* for a hypothetical *Richard* who spent time in Costa Rica — and hence goes by the stressed syllable in the Spanish version of his name, *Ri**car**do*. There's a method to the madness, but there is madness.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Even though etymologically "Ashley" is not a diminutive but two nouns [*ash* + *leah*](https://www.behindthename.com/name/ashley).</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> The original name is the Latin *Antonius*. The *h* was added in English in the 17th century due to an [incorrect connection](https://www.behindthename.com/name/anthony) made with the Greek word *anthos*.</sub>

Comment: Wow.  This is a much better answer than I thought was possible.

Comment: I think Rick/Dick, Will/Bill, ... are due to rhyming: http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2012/04/how-dick-came-to-be-short-for-richard/

Answer (score 2):

Typically a shortened version of a name is a part of the full name.

But as demonstrated by both Beth and Eliza being short for Elizabeth, there's not really any rule about *which* part of the full name we pull out to make the shortened version. Indeed, besides chopping off either the beginning or the end of a name, we sometimes cut out some part of the middle instead: Elizabeth is also commonly shortened to Liz, or, less commonly, Liza.

The more English names you can memorize, the better you'll be at recognizing shortened versions of names and guessing what the full name is. But without asking the person for sure, you'll still just be guessing. For every Elizabeth who goes by Beth, there's another person whose name is just Beth, not short for anything.

The William > Bill thing is kind of a one-off that you just have to memorize. A quick Google search shows that theories on how that came to be include letter-swapping in the Middle Ages. So William became Will, which then became Bill. A similar pattern happens with Richard being shortened to Rick, which then becomes Dick. So now we have Dick as a shorter version of Richard.

Again, you've just gotta memorize those. There's not really any *rules* for names.

Comment: But what about _Betty_ for Elizabeth? And, well, yes, Rick becomes Dick, except when it's Ricky or Dicky, or R.C. (middle name is "Charles", you see). Then again, really _close_ friends call Richard _Card_, which is a shortened _Ricardo_, because when he hung out in Costa Rica, some Ticos started calling him that, and...

Comment: . . . and there are Bert, Bert, and Bert -- er, Hubert, Bertram and Bernard, if we're feeling formal.  They're probably on their way to meet Rock and Rocky -- that is, Roy and Robert.  We call that Robert "Rocky" because we're also friends with a Rob and a Bobby and a Gonzo.  You probably know them through Cliff, right?  By the way, is Cliff short for Clifford or for Heathcliff?  Never mind, I'll ask Gonzo.  One thing you have to say about Robert Gonzales -- he never forgets a name.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan Oh, you mean _"Cube!"_ Well, it was _Hubert_ originally, but he hated that and insisted on _Bert_. There was another Bert in our form, though, and it went from _Hube_ to _Cube_ (Don't get me started on what we used to call old _Cholmondeley_...)

Comment: I hear that people in English-speaking countries actually do not have real choice to name themselves because the usual given names available are limited, with so many possible repetitions  people have to turn to the various shortened forms to make difference.

Comment: @NanningYouth I'm not sure about no real choice. Any individual doesn't necessarily have a choice because their parents do the naming, but you can always legally change your name in adulthood (not sure about all countries, but in some, at least). But there are tens of thousands of possible names to pick from, some more common than others. Or you can just make one up completely.

Comment: @NanningYouth I think in reality shortened names can come about for various reasons. Maybe a child's parents name them after an old relative, but the name as fallen out of style, so they go by a short version that's more contemporary. Maybe a kid's parents never used a shortened name at home, but then the the kid had three others in their preschool class with the same name, so they started going by a short version to differentiate, and it stuck. Maybe the kid just didn't like their own name, so once they got old enough, they decided to go by a different version.

Comment: @NanningYouth Ha! I think we actually have quite a lot of choice here. Compare it to countries that ban names, such as [Sauda Arabia](http://gulfnews.com/news/gulf/saudi-arabia/saudi-arabia-bans-50-baby-names-1.1303898). Many Muslim-majority countries produce a lot of Mohammeds and Maryams. Of course, when Christianity was more the norm in English-speaking countries, there were more [Johns](https://www.behindthename.com/name/john/top) — not that those names have died away, but more have been added. But take this with a grain of salt; I haven't done any research so it's quite subjective...

Comment: It is known that Queen Elizabeth the Sexond is known by the slightly shortened version Lilibet by close family members.

Comment: @cjl750 I think what you said is an ideal state, but the reality is people seldom have choices and they even repeat the names of their ancestors, which is a taboo in some cultures, like that of China. George Bush, there are two of them even in the presidency of the US, it is unbelivable.